# When is it expected to write someone's name correctly?

Tags: citations, etiquette, formatting, personal-name, correspondence

It is generally expected that European names be spelled correctly in academic correspondence and citations. This is expected, even when they use symbols not in the English language, when publishing in English (provided that a modern typesetting system will support it).

For instance, the German name "Müller" is expected to be spelled correctly, even though it could be spelled "Mueller" in the English Alphabet (without loss of information). Similarly, Gaelic names such as "Ó Ceallaigh" would not be Anglicised, despite a long history of this having been done before.

However, this is not the case for Asian languages, even Japanese names where they do not typically have the culture of adopting a nickname in Western Countries. For example, "田中" would be spelled as "Tanaka" to confirm with English language readers, despite Japan having it's own phonetic conventions to give the desired reading (e.g., "タナカ").

For a more comparable example, why is it ok to spell “Tokyo” in English when “Muller” is incorrect. The correct romanisation of 東京 is Tōkyō. Yet this is not used, nor is Toukyou or とうきょう which would both be more accurate. This misspelling occurs for names of people in Asian languages as well as names of places.

It's typically argued that this is because English-speaking audiences could not read Japanese names in their writing system but the same could be said for the umlaut, which is often mispronounced or misused (e.g., Mötley Crüe). With digital typesetting systems, would be entirely possible to spell "田中" correctly in a citation, even by someone who cannot understand the meaning, just as we do for diacritics for European names.

If spelling someone's name correctly is a matter of respect, when is it necessary to do so and why are there exceptions to this?

Comment: To your question, answer is: EVERYTIME.

Comment: @Coder Ideally, yes but we clearly fail to do this. Perhaps there is a rational compromise.

Comment: Tokyo _is_ the (English) name of the city. Some cities - especially big ones - have different names in different countries, and when you are writing in a given language, you should use the given languages names for such places, hence Tokyo.

Comment: It's ok to spell 東京 "Tokio" because it's ok to spell Berlin "ベルリン". You're adapting to your audience.

Comment: I was typing the other half of the point in the bigger field below :)

Comment: @TomKelly in the past we failed to do it because of technical reasons. Nowadays there's no reason to not use the correct spelling, every (decent) software is able to handle all those characters.I mean umlaute are even possible in domain names.

Comment: "Ōsumi" is the correct romanization of a Japanese name? Says who? What if Ōsumi writes his name Osumi when he publishes English papers? Would you still need to spell it Ōsumi when you cite his Japanese papers? I don't know whether Japanese has this problem, but Russian certainly does.

Comment: I think there has been some misunderstanding here. This does not just occur with places with equivalent English names. For example 佐藤 is a very common Japanese name spelled Satō or Satoru. Using “Sato” is as inaccurate as omitting an umlaut and yet far more acceptable. Are more careless because people from Asian cultures are more polite or just because the languages are so different to English?

Comment: *"For instance, the German name "Müller" is expected to be spelled correctly, even though it could be spelled "Mueller" in the English Alphabet (without loss of information)"*. Both "Mueller" and "Müller" exist as names in Germany and cannot be identified back if you translate them, so your "without loss of information" claim is wrong. For this reason if you give "Mueller" as replacement for "Müller" in German legal documents, you are really asking for trouble. "Maße" is also not "Masse". The replacements ae, oe, ue and ss were hacks and are not recommended anymore.

Comment: @Tom Kelly: Omitting an umlaut is less acceptable because it's spelled with an umlaut in German, a language that uses Roman letters. Should the Russian name Чайко́вский be spelled Tchaikovsky or Chaikofskii or Chaikovskii or Chaikovsky or Chaikovskiy or Tschaikowsky or Czajkowski or Čajkovski? Should the Hebrew name שׁוֹר be spelled Shore or Shor or Shorr or Schor or Schorr or Chor or Schur or Schurr or Szor? Why should we treat Japanese any differently from Russian and Hebrew?

Comment: @Peter Shor We shouldn’t give a language special treatment. I’ve just given examples we do and do not conform to conventions of other languages in English. When when it possible to use their characters or there is a standard romanisation we do not.

Comment: @PeterShor There are actually romanization systems for [Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese), [Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian), and other languages (although I didn't find one for German!), so your hypothetical questions actually have somewhat objective answers, depending on the context. There is something special about Japanese in that it has a fairly fixed set of "only" about 100 phonemes that are mapped 1-1 with the Hiragana and Katakana character sets. Other languages, including English, are a lot "messier", phonologically.

Comment: @Todd: I hate to disillusion you, but for Russian, there is no 
"objective" answer. There are half a dozen different [Romanization systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian), and not all Russians like the way their name comes out in English in the official system, so they use their preferred Romanization on scientific papers, and the official one only on their passports. The situation is similar for Hebrew.

Comment: @PeterShor I should have emphasized the "contexts" part of that sentence. Notice you contextualized the romanization examples your gave in your second comment. And I was careful to put "somewhat objective". E.g., in the context of passports, there is an official romanization, which means in that context, the romanization is somewhat objective. That's all I meant. In any case, Hepburn is so popular for Japanese romanization that IMHO romanizing Russian doesn't seem to be the most apt example.

Comment: @Todd: I more or less agree about Hepburn being standard for Japanese. But note that the OP's question isn't just about Japanese.

Comment: Not specifically but I would expect an answer to address cases where there is a widely accepted Romanisation such as Hepburn or Pinyin for Japanese or Chinese respectively.

Answer (score 17):

I think "correctly" is the wrong word to use here, and it will cloud the issue. What's "correct" for a name is somewhat ill-defined (I've known a Risa and a Lisa who both had the same Japanese name. Which of them was incorrect?). The real standard is to spell *in accordance with the person's wishes*.

As a German person, the blanket assertion "the German name "Müller" is expected to be spelled correctly" is not in my experience true. Rather I would say, as the ease of writing the umlaut electronically increases, the likelihood that someone will be unhappy that you didn't bother to make the minimal effort increases too. There are still plenty of systems that only take ascii characters and people will make do with Mueller or even (sigh) Muller. Japanese people know quite well that you probably couldn't read "田中" nor "タナカ", and they will themselves sign their correspondence to you "Tanaka". They won't expect you to make the effort to learn how to read and type kanji, because they know it's exceptionally more difficult than finding a diacritic. (They will however be quite happy if you do manage.)

For citations, the issue is a little different: it is expected that you cite the authors **as written on the paper**. If you are citing an English-language paper, it is very likely that you will be citing "Ryouichi Tanaka and Robert Müller", because that's what they called themselves. If you are citing a Japanese manuscript, you are expected to cite "田中良一　ロバート・ミュラー". Maybe as "田中良一　ロバート・ミュラー (Ryouichi Tanaka and Robert Müller)" if you are yourself writing in English.

To sum up:

- **When is it expected to spell someone's name correctly?** Always, but correctly ≠ in the original alphabet, or following some specific romanization rules.
- **When is it expected to spell someone's name in the original alphabet?** When you can reasonably do so without major effort, and it does not hinder communication.

Comment: I actually find typing Japanese using modern IME support easier than trying to remember the right way of typing ü on a US-mode keyboard/switching to European layout and remembering the right keys to press there.

Comment: If you've set it up in the past, yes. But for someone who's never learned about the Japanese alphabets, setting it up and figuring out how it works would be quite a challenge, not to mention the difficulty in figuring out if you selected the right kanji! The "classic" way of typing ü if you don't have any practice in it is entering "u umlaut" in your search bar...